# Async/Await doens't wait for the previous function to complete

Tags: javascript, ajax, async-await

I'm building a web app that needs to query my database multiple times, each time getting data from the first database call to make the next  call. That being the case, I need to wait until the previous call is completed before continuing. Is async/await not the correct way of doing that? And if so, what am I missing here?

```
var firstCall = new XMLHttpRequest();
var firstCallData;
async function sendFirstCall() {
  firstCall.open('GET', queryURL);
  firstCall.onload = function() {
    firstCallData = JSON.parse(firstCall.responseText);
  };
  firstCall.send();
};

async function logData() {
  await sendFirstCall();
  console.log(firstCallData);
}

logData();
```

I'm not entirely new to JS, but I don't write it that often and I'm definitely not as familiar with how async/await works. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Your `sendFirstCall` function does not return a Promise.

Comment: @Pointy In fact id does (because it's async) but it's a `Promise<void>` which is automaticall resolved.

Comment: @derpirscher yes, right exactly.

Answer (score 2):

The `sendFirstCall` function isn't returning a `Promise` (not a particularly meaningful one anyway), so there's nothing to `await`.  I don't know if `XMLHttpRequest` has any modern `Promise` functionality (tools like `fetch` or Axios do, you might consider looking into those), but you can wrap it in a `Promise`.  Perhaps something like this:

```
function sendFirstCall() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    firstCall.open('GET', queryURL);
    firstCall.onload = function() {
      firstCallData = JSON.parse(firstCall.responseText);
      resolve();
    };
    firstCall.send();
  });
}
```

Note that I also dropped the `async` from the function definition.  It's not really using async/await here, just manually returning a `Promise` (which itself is awaitable, so consuming code can still use `await`).

---

Alternatively, and perhaps more idiomatically, the `Promise` itself can resolve to the data:

```
function sendFirstCall() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    firstCall.open('GET', queryURL);
    firstCall.onload = function() {
      resolve(JSON.parse(firstCall.responseText));
    };
    firstCall.send();
  });
}
```

Then the consuming code would be:

```
firstCallData = await sendFirstCall();
```

That way the operation itself doesn't have side effects, it just (asynchronously) results in a value and the consuming code decides what to do with that value.

---

You might also make use of the `reject` callback within the `Promise` to handle errors, in the event that the `XMLHttpRequest` fails or results in an error code.  Otherwise that failure/error would just be lost and the `Promise` would never resolve or reject.